# How do I register a parameter for a DbContext with Autofac?

Tags: c#, autofac

I am using Entity Framework and Sql to work with a database.

My context class is:

```
 public class AnimalBreedsContext : DbContext
 {
        public DbSet<AnimalBreed> AnimalBreeds { get; set; }

        public AnimalBreedsContext(DbContextOptions<AnimalBreedsContext> options) : base (options)
        {

        }
  }
```

The class AnimalBreeds is a class that has some string properties like Name, etc.

Now I want to register the AnimalBreedsContext class with Autofac. I tried something like that:

```
class ContainerConfig
 {
     public static IContainer Configure()
     {
         var builder = new ContainerBuilder(); 

         var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AnimalBreedsContext>()
                         .UseSqlServer("configString")
                         .Options;

         builder.RegisterType<AnimalBreedsContext>().WithParameter(options).AsSelf();

         return builder.Build();
      }
 }
```

But the problem is that "parameter options can't be converted from AnimalBreedsContext to Autofac.Parameter".

Is there any other option so that I can register this class with Autofac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't providing the correct arguments to `WithParameter`.  [Here is the Autofac documentation](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/78E97FC9.htm) showing all of the overloads.

Without wrapping the argument in one of the Autofac `Parameter` objects, it looks like you can provide the string *name* of the parameter as the first argument, then your actual parameter object as the second:

```
builder.RegisterType<AnimalBreedsContext>()
       .AsSelf()
       .WithParameter("options", options);
```